# How to configure MessagePack on SignalR with Owin and WebApi 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, signalr, owin, self-hosting, msgpack

We have a SignalR service that runs as a self-hosted OWIN app with Web API 2.  It is configured like

```
resolver.Register(typeof(JsonSerializer), () =>  JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings));
app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration { EnableDetailedErrors = true, Resolver = resolver});
```

We want to replace our JsonSerializer with MessagePack.  The obvious examples all configure it from a AspNet.Core web application context.  I can't seem to find any examples with Owin self hosting.

EDIT: It looks like MessagePack is a new ASP.NET Core feature.  We are running the older ASP.NET version and so I guess the real question is how to do binary formatting over ASP.NET SignalR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.  I am migrating my solution to the [AspNetCore version of SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/messagepackhubprotocol?view=aspnetcore-2.1).